# How to Remove white Spaces in my Input Text Box after Data Entry in View page before the form gets submitted MVC ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to do trimming empty Spaces in this Question?I did tried custom binder.Can somebody help me out?I have validated input fields .Later I noticed someone can just enter white space and submit the form. Can someone help me remove white space before text gets submitted.

//Model for Coupon
**Model:**

```
public int CouponId { get; set; }

[Required]
public string CouponCode { get; set; }

[Required]
public int? Discount { get; set; }

public List<CouponModel> GetList()
{
    List<CouponModel> couponList = new List<CouponModel>();
    couponList = db.Coupons.Select(m => new CouponModel
    {
        CouponId = m.CouponId,
        CouponCode = m.CouponCode,
        Discount = m.Discount
    }).ToList();
   //Trim White spaces in Coupon Text box
```

**HTML:**

```
div class="row">
@if (ViewBag.Message == null)
{
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="input-group">
                                  <input id="CouponCode" name="CouponCode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="btnApply" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Apply Coupon</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
}
<div class="col-md-4">
    @ViewBag.Message
</div>
```

//My controller for action
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string CouponCode)
{
    CouponModel model = new CouponModel();
    var cart = (CartModel)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"];
    var coupon = model.GetList().FirstOrDefault(m => m.CouponCode == CouponCode);
    if (coupon != null)
    {
        cart.CouponApplied = true;
        cart.CouponId = coupon.CouponId;
        cart.CouponCode = coupon.CouponCode;
        cart.Price = cart.Price - cart.Price * 20 / 100;
        cart.Total = cart.Price * cart.Quantity;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"] = cart;              

        ViewBag.Message = "Coupon is applied Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Coupon not found or Expired!";
    }
    return View(cart);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please always check **null,string.Empty and WhiteSpace** when you use string.you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)` for **null or empty** value and when you checking **null,string.Empty and WhiteSpace** then you can use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)`.Since .Net Framework 4.0 has a `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method for strings which generalizes the `IsNullOrEmpty()` method to also include other white space besides empty string.

Please try this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string CouponCode)
    {
        CouponCode= CouponCode.Trim();
        var cart =(CartModel)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CouponCode)) 
        {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Your Error Message");//OR something you like.

        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
           CouponModel model = new CouponModel();

        var coupon = model.GetList().FirstOrDefault(m => m.CouponCode == CouponCode);
        if (coupon != null)
        {
            cart.CouponApplied = true;
            cart.CouponId = coupon.CouponId;
            cart.CouponCode = coupon.CouponCode;
            cart.Price = cart.Price - cart.Price * 20 / 100;
            cart.Total = cart.Price * cart.Quantity;
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"] = cart;              

            ViewBag.Message = "Coupon is applied Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Coupon not found or Expired!";
        }  

     }
       return View(cart);
    }
```

Comment: the string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CouponCode) bit is redundant.  You already trimmed it above, it can't be just whitespace anymore.

Comment: you can remove CouponCode= CouponCode.Trim();

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0161 'CartController.Index(string)': not all code paths return a valueControllers\CartController.cs 32 Active

Answer (score 0):

you probably need some kind of regular expression based validation for this.  The pattern would match [^\s]+.  (Ie, valid if it contains any non whitespace character 1 or more times.) You could accomplish this using html5's validation properties.  Pattern is the one you want, and validationmessage can be used to specify the message shown on blur.

It would look like this:

```
<input id="CouponCode" name="CouponCode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code" pattern="[^\s]+" validationmessage="Coupon Code is a required field">
```

However, if you already have validation in place using mvc's validation attributes, and want to be consistent, there's a validation attribute for regular expressions.  That would look like this:

```
[RegularExpression("[^\s]+", ErrorMessage="Coupon Code is a required field")]
```

Comment: I can continue to checkut page without even applying Coupon.So i didnt get why is this Reqex expression needed here?

Comment: The regular expression will prevent somebody from submitting the form with just a space in the text box.  Also, your model has CouponCode marked as [Required], so submitting the form without a CouponCode would not be valid.

Comment: But the thing is even if a customer types a Coupon with spaces,it has to be applied by removing spaces is my neccessity.Thanks Redit0.

Comment: So you really have two issues then.  You want to prevent them from submitting the coupon code with just a space in it, which this does.  But you also want to remove spaces from what they DO submit.  That can be accomplished with a regular expression as well.  In your controller action:

    `Regex.Replace(CouponCode, "[\s]", "");`  This will remove all whitespace characters from the string.

Comment: public int? Discount { get; set; }

        public List<CouponModel> GetList()
        {
            List<CouponModel> couponList = new List<CouponModel>();

            couponList = db.Coupons.Select(m => new CouponModel
            {
                CouponId = m.CouponId,
                CouponCode = m.CouponCode,
                Discount = m.Discount
            }).ToList();

            Regex.Replace(CouponCode, "[\s]", "");

            return couponList;
        }
It says escaped sequence

Comment: Sorry, use two \'s instead of one.

`Regex.Replace(CouponCode, "[\\s]", "");`

Comment: Its not working with that by placing it in my controller!!

Comment: What's not working about it?  The only thing I can think of that would prevent that Regex.Replace from working is if you're not referencing System.Text.RegularExpressions.  Make sure you have at the top:

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a blur event to your input field

```
$("#CouponCode").blur(function() {
    $("#CouponCode").val($("#CouponCode").val().trim());
});
```

this way you don't have to worry about sending a text with empty spaces

here is a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g51qvnha/4/

Comment: Its not getting trimmed when the value is submitted.It doesn't vary when i inserted this code into my Application.

Answer (score 0):

CouponCode = CouponCode.Trim().Replace(" ", "");
This helped